# Features doesn't recognize my drupal version

Tags: files, features

[image]I looked in Status report:

```
Drupal 7.41
```

I get this error:

```
Please enter a valid version with core and major version number. Example: 7.x-1.0
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations but nothing works, what should I put in there?

Additionally, the feature downloads as a .tar file, can I get it to download as a Zip file?

Comment: What happened when you tried the example? Did it not work?

Comment: I added a screen capture

Comment: Which looks nothing like the example right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it...I thought the X in 7.X was supposed to be my sub drupal 7 version = 41, but actually the X has to remain X, not a variable for the version name...got confused...I thought I had to substitute the X with 41 –

Comment: It's not an "example" it should say "put these exactly in there" or have the field autofilled...